# Suggestion with basic drools syntax

Tags: syntax, drools

The following is a basic drools syntax:

```
$customer : Customer( )
Account( ) from $customer.accounts
```

As far as I know the first line create a new variable and assign it to the fact.
However I can't quite understand the second line especially what the "Account()" part means...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written class Customer, or must know it to understand what's going on here. Presumably it contains a `Collection<Account>` accounts (see note), which is (by the engine) retrieved one by one so that the rule fires for each Account object contained in Customer's object.

The rule will fire once for each Account object stored in any of the collections contained in all the Customer facts in working memory, with `$customer` being bound to the containing Customer.

You can bind another variable to Account.

Note: It could also contain a field `Account accounts`, but I hope the name was chosen carefully.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.

My main question remains what happens when written "Account( )"? It returns Account instance that simply wasn't assigned to any variable?

Comment: As written, `Account()` merely "matches" yet another Account and is an indication that the rule should be fired for that. Unless you bind (as I wrote) another variable, you don't have access to this object.